# How do you let variables accessible to other components in Angular?

Tags: angular

Dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { User } from '../auth/user.model'


@Component ({
  selector: "app-dashboard",
  templateUrl: "./dashboard.component.html",
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  constructor (private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getUser()
                    .subscribe(
                      (user: User) => {
                        this.user = user;
                      }
                    )
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/login'])
  }
}
```

The above component is basically nav component, and I have a lot of other components inside of this component. I was wondering how to access the user variable for components inside of this component?

EDIT: I need to rephrase the question. The reason I asked the above question is because of this:

I display user properties in the parent component, like {{ user.name }}. But the children component for this parent produce an error even though I don't use it,

`"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"`

I was guessing that I need to reference the user variable in my child components

Comment: one of https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: By "user variable", do you mean "property"? In general, accessing child component properties is bad practice and reflects poor program design.

Comment: `<child-component [user]="user">`. then `@Input() user;` in your child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a full write up on this in the docs [HERE](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

But there are really 3 methods to component communication.
**`@Input/@Output`**, **`@ViewChild`**, and **A Service**

**`@Input/@Output`:**

This is common for quick, linked changes, especially for things like `ngFor`

```
<div>
    <childComp *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item" (specialEvent)="doSomething()"></childComp>
</div>
```

This lets you pass the "item" to the child, and inside the child you can emit the "specialEvent" and the parent will listen. I have these for components that are complex for display reasons but don't have a ton of logic so they send them up to the parent.

I wouldn't use this method if you intend on being more than one or two levels high.

**`@ViewChild`**:

[`@ViewChild()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child) lets you actually use public methods of child components or change their variables. It's more in-depth than `@Input`but if I'm honest I never use it for that. I almost solely use it for when I need a child element and want to cause an effect or get a value from a DOM object.

```
<div id="moverWrapper" #moverWrap>
    <div class="mover" [ngStyle]="moverStyle()"></div>
</div>

@ViewChild(moverWrap) moverWrap: ElementRef;
let width = this.moverWrap.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
```

**A Service**
As a service is really the best way to do what you want though, I wont go through examples as the link I sent has better ones. But with a value you'd want globally (like the user) you keep that in the service and inject it where you need it.. I use this method 95% of the time.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this task in next way:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service